# How to both upload Electron's crashReporter's minidump file to a remote server and store it locally?

Tags: electron

I'm using Electron's [`crashReporter`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/crash-reporter) API to upload crash reports and dumps to a remote server. This works fine.

I also want to store the crash minidump file locally on the user's machine in case, for any reason, the dump file could not be uploaded to the crash report server. I cannot find a way to do this.

From the docs:

> Crash reports are saved locally in an application-specific temp
>   directory folder. For a productName of YourName, crash reports will be
>   stored in a folder named YourName Crashes inside the temp directory.
>   You can customize this temp directory location for your app by calling
>   the app.setPath('temp', '/my/custom/temp') API before starting the
>   crash reporter.

However, this is what I find there in the `temp` directory

```
3f0afdc3-373b-43c8-8c8b-0246ac88e0d5.txt
crash_checkpoint.txt
operation_log.txt
uploads.log
```

None of these is what I require which is the actual `.dmp` file.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I found that if I set `uploadToServer` to `false`, I can find the crash dump file in the `temp` directory. However, this is not what I want exactly. I want to both upload it to the server and save it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crashReporter` by default falls back on storing the crash dump on the user's local machine if it could not reach the server. So an option to both upload to server and store locally is unnecessary.